# SSIS Execute Process Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression

I'm attempting to use the Execute Process Task in SSIS. Currently I have a hardcoded executable and I have set up an expression for the argument. The expression uses user defined variables.

For some reason the expression is being generated prior to run time when the user variables are generated, this leaves a blank space in sections of my argument field. I've gone ahead and set the DelayValidation property to TRUE in order to prevent it from being validated before runtime, but the issue still occurs.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how/when do you populate the user variables?

Comment: The preceding task is where my variables are populated.

Comment: If you are in 2012 and initialising the variable through expression, you need to make sure that the variable property EvaluateAsExpression is set to true.

Comment: That property is set to true.

Comment: One test you can do to rule out problems with the initialisation is remove the expression from the variable, set EvaluateAsExpression property to false and instead populate it trough a Expression Task added to the Control Flow